# I've messed up my internet. How do I reset all network settings to default on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: wireless, internet, 17.10, vpn

I'm having problems with my wifi connection. So bad that it even breaks my wifi connection so that my other devices can't connect to it, it was fine before trying to mess with vpns. How do I reset everything network related so that I don't have to reinstall ubuntu? This is my third reinstall attempt already, getting tired of it :(

Comment: me too , I try start it with NetworkManager and and network it is disable in next second , it is a wired network

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Network Manager* stores its system-wide configuration in `/etc/NetworkManager`. You can remove it (or, better yet, back it up) and then [restore its default](/q/66533/175814).
2. Reboot Ubuntu or restart *Network Manager* (`systemctl network-manager restart`).